# numpy : View support in CUDA

Tags: numpy, view, gpu, numba, cupy

Does numba+CUDA and/or cupy support numpy views on the GPU ?

Specifically views with different types, like this :

```
In [179]: x = np.random.randint(0,100,(10,5), dtype=np.int16)                                                                                                                

In [180]: y = x[:,4].view(dtype=np.float16)

In [188]: y[:] = 0                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[188]: 
array([[97, 14, 75, 42,  0],
       [30, 87, 78, 62,  0],
       [23, 92, 90, 37,  0],
       [15, 12, 58, 36,  0],
       [21, 32, 88, 83,  0],
       [99, 70, 92, 16,  0],
       [ 3, 88, 93, 16,  0],
       [52, 32, 24, 15,  0],
       [52, 99, 17, 97,  0],
       [20, 33, 59, 56,  0]], dtype=int16)  

In [191]: y                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[191]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float16)
```

I need float16 to work

numba: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4402

cupy seems to have some support for float16